# Finding parameter $x$ of a system of linear equation $\boldsymbol{A}(x)\,\boldsymbol{c}=\boldsymbol{0}$ leading to non-trivial solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, parametric

I am wondering, which possiblities exist to find the parameter $x$ in a system of linear equations
$$\boldsymbol{A}(x)\,\boldsymbol{c}=\boldsymbol{0}$$
leading to a non-trivial solution $\boldsymbol{c}$. The dependency of $\boldsymbol{A}$ of $x$ should be arbitrary (non-linear).

I know that I can use $\mathrm{det}(\boldsymbol{A}(x))=0$ to find the values of $x$ leading to a non-trivial solution, but that seems to be rather instable from a numerical point, especially if the matrix dimension becomes larger. Are there other conditions, which can be used in numerical algorithms?

Edit: $\boldsymbol{A}(x)$ can be complex valued and is square.

Edit 2: If it narrows the problem a bit, the entries of $\boldsymbol{A}(x)$ are of the form $a_1\,x^n\sin(a_2x)$, $b_1\,x^n\cos(b_2x)$, $c_1\,x^n\exp(c_2x)$ with $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $c_1$, $c_2$ arbitrary complex constants.

Edit 3: $x$ is generally also complex valued

Comment: If it's a square matrix, $\det(A(x)) = 0$ is precisely the equation you need to solve.  In some particular cases there may be some simplification possible, but I don't see how you can hope for "other conditions".

Comment: I read for example that using something like $\mathrm{cond}(\boldsymbol{A}(x))\rightarrow\infty$ could also be applied in a numerical algorithm, where $\mathrm{cond}(\bullet)$ is the conditioning number of the matrix. Maybe there are other possibilities.

Comment: Whether the solution of $\operatorname{det} A(x)=0$ is stable or not depends on how that expression is defined in terms of  $x$. An "arbitrary (non-linear)" dependence leaves too much to the imagination.  At a minimum one needs to be able to *evaluate* that determinant for specific $x$.

Comment: This is a horrible idea in a number of ways, but I'll propose it anyways. You could write a piece of code which computes the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda(x)$ of $A(x)$ in magnitude for a particular value of $x$. Then solve $\lambda(x) = 0$ using your favorite nonlinear solver. (You _might_ even be able to  get automatic differentiation to work so that you can compute $\lambda'(x)$ and use a gradient-based method.)